# How to save data to cassandra columfamily using hector with two primary keys?

Tags: java, cassandra, hector

I'm using cassandra 1.1.4 and Hector 1.0.2 and I have been given a columfamily definition that maps to an xls doc and from that we want to store data as follows:

```
create table test(
firstId int,
secondId varchar,
somedata varchar,
moredata varchar,
PRIMARY KEY (firstId, secondId));
```

This is what the user requires but how can I model this in Hector.  Currently I can use the Mutator's `addInsertion(Key k, String cf, HColumn<N,V> sc)` for a single key, but is there any way to do it with two primary keys and of different data types?

Any assistance appreciated, even if it's not possible using Hector then something else.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Cassandra is a key value database. It can't have two keys. What it can have is a composite key, which can consist of your two so called 'primary keys'. For example, if one of them is Integer, one of them is Long, you would construct the key like this (Pelops)

```
Bytes.composite()
   .addInt(firstKeyVal)
   .addLong(secondKeyVal)
.build();
```

With pure Thrift you can do exactly the same.
In hector, you might be a bit restricted upon what you do in the sense you can't as easily achieve composite keys. However, it is possible. I am linking to it:

[How to define composite key for a column family and then reference it using Hector?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7329211/)

Comment: Thank you for your reply, I think this will really help me a lot as I didn't know how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

use CompositeType - [How to define composite key for a column family and then reference it using Hector?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7329211/how-to-define-composite-key-for-a-column-family-and-then-reference-it-using-hect)

You row key would look like: firstId:secondId